# postfix MX host not found

Tags: linux, email, postfix

Im am trying to send mail using Postfix, but I get the following error for all emails:

```
May 13 12:44:46 myhost postfix/qmgr[12169]: A6D9644526: from=<x@y.com>, size=317, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

May 13 12:44:46 myhost postfix/smtp[12178]: A6D9644526: to=<z@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=0.03, delays=0.02/0/0/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=gmail.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)
```

Reading the linked questions, I have already checked `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/var/spool/postfix/etc/resolv.conf` they both are same. my `resolv.conf` looks like :

```
nameserver 2001:4b98:dc0:49::225
nameserver 217.70.184.225
nameserver 217.70.184.226
options timeout:1 attempts:3 rotate
```

`dig mx gmail.com` works:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.8-Ubuntu <<>> mx gmail.com ;; global
 options: +cmd ;; Got answer: ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status:
 NOERROR, id: 64383 ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY:
 4, ADDITIONAL: 15
```

Here is the content of `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = myhost
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

Any idea why the mail host is not found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the error was due to the ipv6 address in /etc/resolv.conf.
I removed it and it now works.

Comment: How did it get there in the first place? If it is was through dhcp it will come back.